# Why didn't Dumbledore enchant a portrait of himself to aid the trio in their hunt for Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter

Why didn't Dumbledore enchant a portrait of himself to aid the trio in their hunt for Horcruxes?

Surely, if he foresaw Ron leaving and coming back, reason for why he left him the Deluminator via his last will and testament, and that Harry and Hermione would have to compensate for the decreased magical capacity/capability provided by Ron while he was absent, then he would have thought of a way to help them (via a portrait). He could have also taught the Fidelius Charm to them, seeing as how that prevented the Death Eaters from entering 12 Grimmauld Place even though they were aided by the Taboo Jinx/Curse, but Hermione's protective enchantments (Protego Totalum, Salvio Hexia, Repello Muggletum, Muffliato, Cave Inimicum, Disillusionment Charm, etc...) collapsed entirely against the Taboo Jinx/Curse. There might be other times during the Horcrux hunt where he would have been helpful, but these are the only ones I could think of right now.

The quote proving that Dumbledore knew that Ron would leave and comeback is here, in page 391, British Edition, of Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows:

> And still his scar prickled, and he knew that Voldemort was getting there too. Harry understood, and yet did not understand. His instinct was telling him one thing, his brain quite another. The Dumbledore in Harry’s head smiled, surveying Harry over the tips of his fingers, pressed together as if in prayer.
>   **You gave Ron the Deluminator. You understood him ... you gave him a way back** ...
>   And you understood Wormtail too ... you knew there was a bit of regret there, somewhere ...
>   And if you knew them ... what did you know about me, Dumbledore?
>   Am I meant to know, but not to seek? Did you know how hard I’d find that? Is that why you made it this difficult? So I’d have time to work that out?

Comment: Rather obvious plot hole in retrospect. I would upvote this twice if I could.